# Manejo de nulos y vacíos en PHP con isset, empty, is_null

Tags: php

Como sabemos, el manejo de los nulos, de los vacíos, de los en blanco y otros familiares representan siempre un punto delicado en programación.

Un manejo y evaluación no adecuado de los mismos podría arrojar resultados erróneos, de ahí la inquietud de plantear esta pregunta con auto-respuesta, que quedará marcada como Wiki de comunidad.

**¿Cómo comprender y manejar los nulos en PHP?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP tiene básicamente tres funciones para el manejo de nulos, vacíos, en blanco, no declarados.

Veamos la definición de cada una.

### [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Determina **si una variable está definida y no es `NULL`**.

Si una variable ha sido removida con `unset()`, esta ya no estará definida. `isset()` devolverá `FALSE` si prueba una variable que ha sido definida como `NULL`. También tenga en cuenta que un byte `NULL ("\0")` no es equivalente a la constante `NULL` de PHP.

Si son pasados varios parámetros, entonces `isset()` devolverá `TRUE` únicamente si todos los parámetros están definidos. La evaluación se realiza de izquierda a derecha y se detiene tan pronto como se encuentre una variable no definida.

***Valores devueltos:***

Devuelve `TRUE` si `var` existe y tiene un valor distinto de `NULL`, de lo contrario devuelve `FALSE`.

---

### [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Determina **si una variable está vacía**.

Una variable se considera vacía si no existe o si su valor es igual a `FALSE`. `empty()` no genera una advertencia si la variable no existe.

En las versiones anteriores a PHP 5.5, `empty()` sólo soportaba variables; cualquier otra cosa provocaría un error del intérprete. En otras palabras, lo siguiente no funcionaría: `empty(trim($nombre))`. En su lugar, habría que utilizar `trim($nombre) == false`.

No se genera una advertencia si la variable no existe. Esto significa que `empty()` es esencialmente el equivalente conciso de `!isset($var) || $var == false`.

***Valores devueltos:***

Devuelve `FALSE` si `var` existe y tiene un valor no vacío, distinto de cero. De otro modo devuelve `TRUE`.

Las siguientes expresiones son consideradas como vacías:

- `""` (una cadena vacía)
- `0` (0 como un integer)
- `0.0` (0 como un float)
- `"0"` (0 como un string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (un array vacío)
- `$var;` (una variable declarada, pero sin un valor)

---

### [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-null.php)

Comprueba si la variable dada es `NULL`.

***Valores devueltos:***

Devuelve `TRUE` si `var` es `null`, `FALSE` de lo contrario.

Una variable es considerada `null` si:

- se le ha asignado la constante `NULL`.
- no se le ha asignado un valor todavía.
- se ha destruido con `unset()`.

---

### Probando las diversas posibilidades con cada función.

[Código fuente](https://gist.github.com/phpfiddle/87c9cf863132ee77b3aa518a6e09b850)

```
| Valor                     | Tipo      | isset(var)    | empty(var)    | is_null(var)  | if(var)   |
| ---                       | ---       | ---           | ---           | ---           | ---       |
| vacio ("")                | string    | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| en blanco (" ")           | string    | true          | false         | false         | true      |
| NULL                      | NULL      | false         | true          | true          | false     |
| TRUE                      | boolean   | true          | false         | false         | true      |
| FALSE                     | boolean   | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| 0 (como cadena)           | string    | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| 0 (como entero)           | integer   | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| 0.0 (como float)          | double    | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| arr                       | array     | true          | true          | false         | false     |
| Declarada pero sin valor  | NULL      | false         | true          | true          | false     |
| No declarada              | NULL      | false         | true          | true          | false     |
| byte null \0              | string    | true          | false         | false         | true      |
```

**Tabla HTML**

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
border: 1px solid #999;
padding: 0.5rem;
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>isset(var)</th>
      <th>empty(var)</th>
      <th>is_null(var)</th>;
      <th>if(var)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vacio ("")</td>
      <td>string</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>en blanco (" ")</td>
      <td>string</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TRUE</td>
      <td>boolean</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FALSE</td>
      <td>boolean</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0 (como cadena)</td>
      <td>string</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0 (como entero)</td>
      <td>integer</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0.0 (como float)</td>
      <td>double</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>arr</td>
      <td>array</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Declarada pero sin valor</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No declarada</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>byte null \0</td>
      <td>string</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Por lo tanto, ¿Isset es una mezcla de las otras dos no? Nulo + Vacio.

Comment: @GDP no exactamente, `isset` evalúa dos cosas: la **existencia** y la **no nulidad**. Fíjate que en la tabla, `isset` devuelve `true` cuando se trata de una cadena vacía.