# ¿Cómo atrapar error en variables vacías try catch - PHP?

Tags: php, variables, session

Cuando se abre una página sólo con estos datos:

```
<?php
$value  = $_POST['value'];

echo $value;
```

Va a mostrar siempre un error común como este:

> Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs.. on line 2

He observado que se puede atrapar los errores utilizado `catch` pero no me parece correcto atraparlos lo más correcto es validarlos.

**¿Me pueden explicar como funciona este método?**

```
try {
  # code...

} catch {
    # catch error / Since it's a decline will be caught
}
```

La [documentación de php sobre este tema no es tan enriquecido](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php) no existe mucha explicacion.

```
try {
    #code ...
} catch () {
    echo("Error no se recibieron los datos");
    $declined = true;
}
if(!$declined) {
    echo ("Se recibieron los datos");
}
```

Al recibir datos correctamente muestre este mensaje de error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: declined in  C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 8

Al no recibir datos no ejecuta algún error solo muestra su mensaje definido.

*Error no se recibieron los datos*

Comment: Si te refieres al caso específico de `$_POST`, la mejor forma de validarla es con [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), la cual hace dos comprobaciones: 1. Si la variabe está definida, 2. Si no es nula. `if (isset($_POST['value'])){//tiene datos}else{//no tiene datos}`

Comment: @A.Cedano si la mayor parte me refiero al caso del `$_POST` pero en mi nueva actualización una variable `false` no muestra error, pero cuando esta se vuelve `true` muestra un error ¿Porque?

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta realmente, no se dispara un error porque no es un error. Si queres disparar un error, usas  `throw new Exception('Undefined variable');`

Comment: @AlexAngelico Más allá de lo que has mencionado cuando existen datos recibidos me muestra este mensaje personalizado: ***Se recibieron los datos*** pero a la vez este error: ***Notice: Undefined variable: declined in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 8*** y cuando no se reciben datos me muestra este mensaje personalizado: ***Error no se recibieron los datos*** sin mensaje de error de php de **Notice:**

Comment: @AlexAngelico Porqué me muestra el error en esta variable `!$declined` cuando esta recibe valor a mostrar, en este caso el mensaje personalizado.

Comment: si, por supuesto. El notice es un nivel de error de PHP. Es solo una notificacion no es un error. Lo que te dice es que la variable `$declined` no está definida porque no entró en el catch, entonces estas usando la variable en `if (!$declined)` pero esa variable no fue definida anteriormente.

Comment: Oscar el mensaje es evidente, estas evaluando `$declined` sin haberla declarado. Para evitar eso, puedes declarar `$declined` al principio del código con un valor prederminado, `true` o `false`, el cual irás cambiando según lo que ocurra en el código. De ese modo, la variable actuará como un identificador que podrás evaluar en cualquier momento. No es una buena práctica de programación intentas usar variables que no están definidas. Si programas en otros lenguajes que no te permiten ciertas cosas que PHP si te permite te darás cuenta de la diferencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo pueden añadir una pregunta de ambos casos por ejemplo A.Cedano su primer comentario y lo otro que has mencionado para terminar este tema como solucionado gracias :)

Comment: Gran parte de su pregunta está relacionada con  [Manejo de nulos y vacíos en PHP con isset, empty, is\_null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101123/manejo-de-nulos-y-vac%c3%ados-en-php-con-isset-empty-is-null)

Comment: Has revisado la función `empty` de `PHP` determina si una variable está vacía ( http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php ). Asi evitiras tanto código, para un pàso tan simple como `if(empty($_POST['value'])) { echo 'No llego el dato'; } else { $value  = $_POST['value']; echo $value;  }`

Comment: @Dev.Joel No es una pregunta duplicada estoy tomando referencia sobre `try catch` el tema que has enlazado es muy diferente.

Comment: @Oscar con la edición perdió un poco de relevancia el duplicado , pero igual lo agregué porque no es necesario un `try catch` para evaluar variables vacías. Igual ya tiene una respuesta acertada ,Saludos.

Comment: @Dev.Joel A veces no es necesaria pero en otros términos a futuro sí quizás no en el ejemplo dado sino en algo más complejo... Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres al caso específico de $_POST, la mejor forma de validarla es con [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), la cual hace dos comprobaciones:

1. Si la variabe está definida,
2. Si no es nula.

Por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])){

//tiene datos

}else{

//no tiene datos

}
```

Para otros casos, tú puedes usar una variable con valor booleano como bandera, a la cual la vas cambiando el valor según lo que ocurra en el código.

En ese caso la variable puede estar definida de antemano con un valor predeterminado, de ese modo, existirá ocurra lo que ocurra.

(He cambiado el sentido del código, porque estaba un poco al revés, creo).

```
$bolEstado=true;

try {
    #code ...
} catch () {
    echo("Error no se recibieron los datos");
    $bolEstado = false;
}
if($bolEstado) {
    echo ("Se recibieron los datos");
}
```

Pase lo que pase `$bolEstado` existirá, porque está definida antes del bloque `try`.

Comment: al revés o no funcionó sobre todo el `try catch` algo no me queda claro dentro del `if (isset($_POST['value'])){` donde debe ir la variable `$value  = $_POST['value'];` y el `false` que debe ir ???

Comment: @Oscar si quieres puedes hacer esto: `if (isset($value)){ //$value = $_POST['value']; }else{//no hay datos en el POST}`. Lo del `false` en el `if` lo cambié según mi lógica..., partiendo de tu mensaje `Se recibieron datos`.  Para mi se recibirán datos cuando el `try` funcione. Y si no funciona entrará en el `catch` y allí la variable `$bolEstado` adquirirá el valor `false`.  Tu evaluación imprimía el mensaje cuando la variable era `false`. En el fondo de lo mismo. Si quieres dejarlo como estaba, declaras la variable en `false` al inicio y cambias el `if` a como lo tenías.