# Sirve de algo comprobar con empty si ya tengo un request method?

Tags: php, post, isset

tengo una duda estoy haciendo un log in como proyecto básico y lo que hago es en el php recibo

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
       
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pswd'])){
                if(empty($_POST['email'])){
                    echo "<p class='alerta'>TIENES QUE LLENAR EL EMAIL</p>";
                }else{
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                }
                if(empty($_POST['pswd'])){
                    echo "<p class='alerta'>TIENES QUE LLENAR LA CONTRASEÑA</p>";
                }
                /*else{
                    header("Location: principal.php");
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

No acabo de entender muy bien el tema del empty, hago que si lo recibe por el método post, pero luego no entiendo el como usar el empty si al final no lo recibe por metodo post no entrara no ? Luego ya compruebo que existan los valores de email y contraseña con isset. La verdad es que el profesor no lo ha dejado muy claro y por internet solo encuentro que me lio más.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda en concreto? El primer `if` es para que el código solo funcione cuando se use el método POST. Luego puedes usar empty para verificar email y pswd guardándolos en una variable y luego verificar esas variables en lugar del isset, pero para eso tendrías que usar ternarios. Dado que es un contexto de clase no sé si esté permitido.

Comment: Ahora entiendo el primer if, pero entonces en vez de hacer un if(empty($_POST)) dices de meterlo en una variable y verificar más tarde  el correo y pwd?

Comment: Si te permiten usar ternarios puedes hacer algo así: `$email=!empty($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : NULL;` e igualmente con el password y luego verificas así: `if ($email) {` así ya tienes el dato en la variable y el código queda más limpio y no necesitas usar isset. Lo que pasa es que no se refleja con claridad en tu código que validaciones deben hacerse ni en qué orden ¿? Eso es fundamental para responder de la mejor manera a tu pregunta.

Comment: Creo que ha salido, pero muy poco el tema de ternarios. Lo que pasa es que en este caso estamos obligados a usar empty y isset y a veces me cuesta ver la diferencia entre ellos. Lo que quiero verificar tambien es que cuando reciba el pwd y email valide que los campos no esten vacios/no tengan datos y si es asi que salte un error.

Comment: Revisa el manual, allí te explica lo que hace [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) y lo que hace [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php). En base o lo que hayas asimilado escribe tu código y si no lo entiendes reformula la pregunta exponendo tu duda concreta y las limitaciones que tienes (un ejercicio donde debes usar solamente tal o cual función).

Comment: Revisa también [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101123/29967) donde se aborda la diferencia entre los dos.

Comment: bueno aquí una duda que tengo es que en este caso el primer if valida en caso de que sea post, pero no entiendo del todo realmente que hace !empty(_$POST) esta mirando que los datos pasados por post no esten vacios ?

Comment: El primer `if`  solamente evalúa el mètodo, que podría ser POST, GET, PUT, etc, y el  `if ($_POST) {` evalúa que se haya enviado algo. Por ejemplo, puedes tener un formulario con método POST, y darle a enviar sin llenar ninguno de sus campos. Ahí el método será POST, pero en `$_POST`, que es la superglobal que se crea cuando se envía por ese método, no habrá nada, porque el formulario se mandó vacío.

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones y voy con la mía: Algunas de esas validaciones me parecen redundantes: a) El segundo `if` no lo veo necesario, porque después analizas cada campo. b) En vez de usar `isset()`, yo usaría solo `empty()` porque devuelve verdadero si la variable no existe o tiene un valor que, convertido a booleano, resulta en falso. [Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php) c) El uso de `isset()` puede dar _resultados inesperados_, en todo caso, la verificación de un elemento en `$_POST` debería hacerse con `array_key_exists()`