# Formulario con "value" muestra dato en post pero no imprime con echo

Tags: php, post

Tengo un problema con la recepción del valor $id en el siguiente código:

```
if($accion!=""){
    switch($accion){
case 'Seleccionar':
            echo "Presionaste seleccionar";
            echo $id; //este valor $id no se muestra;
        break;
}
```

El valor se toma de este formulario:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $alumno['id'];?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar" name="accion" >
</form>
```

Estoy haciendo un print_r($_POST); y la verdad es que es valor se muestra asi:

```
Array ( [id] => 8 [accion] => Seleccionar )
```

La variable id esta definida como:

```
$id=isset($_POST['id]'])?$_POST['id']:'';
```

No tiene sentido para mi. Si el valor id se esta mostrando en el array del print_r, ¿por qué no se muestra en el "echo $id"?

Comment: Hola Ricardo! Has comprobado que la variable $id esté correctamente definida?

Comment: Pienso que si. Acabo de actualizar la pregunta y podrás ver como la tengo definida.

Comment: Has insertado este código `$id=isset($_POST['id]'])?$_POST['id']:'';` antes del `switch`, verdad?

Comment: Ok tienes razón. Está mal definida. Las comillas del id me traicionaron.
<code>$id=isset($_POST['id']])?$_POST['id']:''; </code> es lo correcto. Gracias

Comment: Me alegro de haberte podido ayudar

Comment: Desde PHP 7+ puedes usar fusión de null, algo así: `$id=$_POST['id'] ?? '';`, anterior a PHP 7 me gusta más usar `empty()`, en lugar de `isset()` algo así: `$id=!empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] :  '';`

Comment: @A. Cedano Muy interesante, gracias. Lo probaré. ¿Es sólo cuestión de gusto o tiene más funcionalidad o seguridad?

Comment: No es sólo cuestión de gustos, sino de la seguridad de lo que quieras evaluar. [Revisa aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101124/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: @A. Cedano Siempre aprendo con sus comentarios. En este caso hay sutiles pero al parecer grandes diferencias. ¿En casos podría dar isset() problemas? En este momento no alcanzo a ver.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si en el input se envía una cadena en blanco (segundo caso de la tabla), la verificación con `isset` pasaría, en cambio, con `empty` no pasaría.

Comment: Gracias, voy a estudiar esos casos.